# Read multiple user input words and split them

Tags: java, split, user-input

Example: peter pan (or) jasmine cornflower

I want to read that in java, but want to split up the name and surname, 
for example, when user enter name and surname it must split it up and write name to name field and surname (second word) to surname field in database table USERS.

Is that possible?
If so how do I go about doing it?

Comment: did you try split() in String class?

Comment: You can use a Scanner to read the user input into String objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class and its split method.

```
String fullName = "peter pan";
String[] nameParts = name.split(" ");

System.out.println(nameParts[0] +" "+ nameParts[1]); // outputs peter pan
```

Comment: the name will always be different and never peter pan

Comment: @user1759247 Azodious was just explaining the concept. Now you can go ahead and apply it to your scenario.

Comment: its working,
what i actually wanted is when i execute my jar with parameters that it then reads the parameters. example. (java -jar myApp.jar peter pan) peter pan will never be the same as the user will input his name and surname?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
    String input = "peter  pan";
    String[] split = input.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println("First name: " + split[0] + ", last name: " + split[1]);
```

the output:

```
    First name: peter, last name: pan
```

If you want to read from the command line, you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args.length >= 2) {
     System.out.println("First name: " + args[0] + ", last name: " + args[1]);
   }
   else {
     System.out.println("Not enough arguments provided.\nInput line as array: "
         + Arrays.toString(args));
   }
 }
```

Comment: its working, what i actually wanted is when i execute my jar with parameters that it then reads the parameters. example. (java -jar myApp.jar peter pan) peter pan will never be the same as the user will input his name and surname?